# How to loop through multiple cells in Jupyter / iPython Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've got a Jupyter Notebook with a couple hundred lines of code in it, spread across about 30 cells.  If I want to loop through 10 cells in the middle (e.g. using a For Loop), how do you do that?  Is it even possible, or do you need to merge all the code in your loop into one cell?

Comment: That's exactly right, this is a duplicate, and the answer referenced above is a better answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I can see to do it would be to join the cells, and then put the entire thing in a for/while loop.